# Photoshop PDF looks different in another reader

Tags: pdf, fonts, photoshop

When i save a .psd to a Photoshop PDF, some fonts don't look like they looked in Photoshop.
They are not completely filled like they are in Photoshop. See the attachments:

1. This is how it looks like in PhotoShop:

   https://s30.postimg.org/hhzop7ksh/Screen_Shot_2014_12_15_at_13_32_23.png

   [image]
2. And this is what it looks like in, for example, google chrome's PDF reader.

   https://s30.postimg.org/v06l1hwxt/Screen_Shot_2014_12_15_at_13_43_54.png

   [image]

As you see, there is a white area in the font. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure this is a *programming related* question? (That would mean, are you working for Adobe?) Perhaps better suited at [graphicdesign.se]. By the way: the canonical "good" PDF reader is Acrobat Reader. For all others the output may differ.

Comment: please share the PDF in question.

Answer (score 2):

I bet the PDF you created from Photoshop did not ***embed*** all fonts used by the PDF.

The consequence is that any PDF reader having to deal with this document needs to use a substitute font.

How to fix this? The first step is: ***make sure your Photoshop-created PDF does embed all the fonts it uses.*** (Then see, if that is already doing what you expect, or if there are more fixes needed.)